# Function using *args to display multiple columns of DataFrame in lineplot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, args

I want to implement a function in my python code, using *args. It should be able to use the columns of a data frame passed as arguments to make a line plot from the selected.

Lets say I have a DataFrame like this:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
x = range(10)

data1 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)
data2 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)
data3 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 10)

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": data1, "col2": data2, "col3": data3}, index = x)
```

The easy but inflexible way to go for a distinct number of arguments passed to the function:

```
%matplotlib inline

def showlineplot(df, x, y, z):
    x = df[x]
    y = df[y]
    z = df[z]

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y, 'z': z})

    df2.plot()
    return

showlineplot(df, "col1", "col2", "col3")
```

Because I have a large DataFrame with 30+ columns containing values, I would be very happy to have a function that can make a variable selection of columns to plot their values in a line plot.

I therefore found *args to be good to use in a function for plotting, and did:

```py
def showlineplot(df, *args):

    newdf = pd.DataFrame()
    for arg in args:
        for i in range(len(args)):
            i = df[arg]
            newdf.append(i)

    newdf.plot()

showlineplot(df, "col1", "col2")
```

I found out 2 mistakes:

firstly, the newdf makes the actual columns of df as rows, and the index is now used in the columns. This makes a plotting impossible.

second, the inner for loop used is making a problem. I placed it because my previous try

```py
for arg in args:
    arg = df[arg]
    newdf = pd.DataFrame({str(arg): arg})
```

shows I need an iterable to link the different `df[args]` to.

Someone has any better idea or can help me with the concept of args in this relation? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) easily, without necessarily write a separate function.
E.g. if you only want to plot the first and third columns of your example dataframe:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col3']
df.loc[:, cols].plot()
```

should do.